# Can't figure out which function called when

Tags: javascript, scope

There is an `elements` object, which is not Array but array-like HTML object.
I need to `alert` `innerHTML` of each `element` in 1 second after `click` on it.
I wrote this code (below), but it doesn't work.

```
[].forEach.call(elements, function (element) {
    element.onclick = () => setTimeout(alert(element.innerHTML), 1000);
});
```

I intuitively know that there is an error in this code (even without its execution), but I don't know where and what is it like (something wrong with arguments maybe?).
Use of `forEach` is mandatory (indexer `i` is used in original code).

---

Perhaps omitting insignificant details of the problem, I missed something meaningful. So I bring a more complete piece of code:

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

colors.forEach(function (color, i) {
    var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    span.style.backgroundColor = color;
    span.tabIndex = i + 1;
    span.onclick = () => setTimeout(console.log(span.innerHTML), 1000);
    fragment.appendChild(span);
});
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Errors in the console? Wrong behavior?

Comment: @Juhana: Wrong behavior. It cannot find variable `element` (it is undefined in global scope).

Comment: Wait what? Of course `element` is not defined in global scope, but what does that matter? You are not trying to access it in global scope.

Comment: @FelixKling: Really? :)

Comment: Do you *know* that it's undefined (the console should show an error) or did you just guess that it's the issue?

Comment: @Juhana: I know it, it was a sort of sarcasm.

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky - do you notice that `alert` appears without 1 second delay?

Comment: @Dmitry: Not sure how I should interpret your response to my comment, but yes, really.

Comment: You're not showing your actual code. The variable is always defined in the code you've shown in the question.

Comment: `element` is local variable in the scope of `forEach`, it is obvious.

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky: Then why did you say the issue is *"It cannot find variable `element` (it is undefined in global scope)"*. If `element` has the **value** `undefined` (which I assume that is what you mean, but not sure), then `elements` may not be what you think it is. The variable `element` definitely exists where you access it.

Comment: @FelixKling: Sorry for misunderstanding. The main issue is described in question: I need to `alert` `innerHTML` of each `element` in 1 second after `click` on it.

Comment: @Dmitry: That's not the issue, that is your goal. What is the *problem* with your code? There is an obvious problem (which is why I closed it as duplicate) but there seems to be something else based on your comment (but it's not clear what exactly it is).

Comment: @FelixKling: I don't know. It just doesn't work the way I want. It returns "`element` is undefined". I can understand why it returns this error, but I can't understand why the whole code doesn't work.

Comment: The code doesn't return anything... where / how do you see that message? Please use precise language to describe the issue. Things would be a lot easier if you'd provide a complete example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @FelixKling: I got it. The _problem_  occured because I used `with` incorrectly (in other part of code). Shame on me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap alert in one more anonymous function:

```
[].forEach.call(elements, function (element) {
    element.onclick = () => setTimeout(() => alert(element.innerHTML), 1000);
});
```

otherwise it is `setTimeout(alert(element.innerHTML), 1000);` when transpiled and you need `setTimeout(function() {alert(element.innerHTML)}, 1000);`